# How to get Start and End IDs of Continues data in Value column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

Hi I have following data in the table as below:

[image: Source Table]

I am looking for below output,

[image: Output]

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.
I just tried with self joining the table with ID1 = ID2+1 and Values not equal conditions.

```
Select    T1.ID as ID1 ,T1.Value V1 ,T2.ID as ID2, T2.Value as V2 From [Test_Seq] T1 
                INNER Join [Test_Seq] T2 
                 on T2.ID = T1.ID+1  
                 Where T1.Value <>T2.Value
```

its giving me below output,

[image: Result Set]

I hope I will get better answer here with clear explanation on this kind of scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Post the query you used.

Comment: I added the query in post.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this query

```
;with cte as (
select *, row_number() over(partition by value order by id) as rn1,  row_number() over(order by id) rn from #startend
) , cte2 as (
select min(id) startid, max(id) as endid, value, rn-rn1 as r from cte
group by rn-rn1, value
) select startid, endid, value from cte2
order by startid
```

Comment: This is what i looking for .. I thought the same it can be achieved by recursive query. Thanks lot. Is there any other way to attain the same?

Comment: Thanks, It is not recursive query though.. i think we can achieve this with rank and dense_rank along with windowing function... we can try

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(id) as startid, max(id) as endid, value from (
 select id, value, id-row_number() over (partition by value order by id) as tmp from YourTableName
) T
 group by value, tmp
 order by 1
```